# Get most popular items in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

My simplified domain model in grails is like this:

```
Article {
    Integer totalViews
    static hasMany = [
        ratings: Rating
    ]
}

Rating {
    Integer value // 1 to 5
    User user
}
```

I am trying to find the 5 most popular articles based on totalViews and ratings, say 25% weightage on views and 75% weightage on ratings.

How would you do it in Groovy/Grails?

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing Apples (ratings) with Oranges (views). Could you precise the kind of algorithm you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably try that with an HQL query, the criteriaBuilder version would be pretty hairy.

I'm not sure what the best alogrithm for the weighting you want would be. But without that, you'd need something like:

```
from Article a order by avg(a.ratings.value) desc, a.totalViews desc
```

Then limit the query to 5 results

```
Article.executeQuery('from Article...', max:5)
```